# UITabBar is changing color on screen change

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, swift4, uitabbar, xcode9, uitabbaritem

I am workingwith xcode9 and Swift 4. In my application I am using a tab bar. Which looks like this normally.

[image]

But on few screens as soon as i land it changes the background color and shows something like this. Can someone point out why this happening??

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have set the background color of tabbar when push to some other controller.

Comment: I did check in my code but I am not setting any background color anywhere.

Comment: Is this UITabBarController or custom UITabBar?

Comment: This is UITabBarController.